# How to include css in a hmvc setup in codeigniter

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter-2, hmvc

I have setup the combination Codeigniter + HMVC + Twitter Bootstrap using [this tutorial](http://www.quizld.com/2012/05/how-to-set-up-hmvc-in-codeigniter-2-1/).
I have created two modules named app and session.
The app module contains the [twitter bootstrap sample](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/carousel.html).
When I click on About link, a new login page is displayed which is the session module configured using

```
<?php echo Modules::run('session/session/index'); ?>
```

The problem I am facing is that when I include the twitter bootstrap in both the views, the app module gets realigned and corousal doesnt work.

How do I get the CSS to work with the session module ?

Comment: Not interested in answers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your CSS files are in the CSS folder at the root level, which is probably a good idea (same level where you have your Application folder) you simply include them in your template by doing :

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>css/mystylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet'>
```